# Como reemplazar todos los caracteres de un string por otro, dependiendo si aparece mas de una vez

Tags: python, lista

Dado un string determinado quiero reemplazar por un "/" si la letra aparece solo una vez, o un "\"
si aparece mas de una vez.

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente str: "Camara"

Quiero que tras pasar por una funcion el output sea: "/\ /\ /\"

Lo que se me ha ocurrido es convertir el str en una lista (con la función *.split()*) para comprobar cuales elementos están por duplicado utilizando un loop para iterar sobre cada elemento de dicha lista. Pero no estoy seguro sobre como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` no te va a construir una lista con los caracteres, si quieres una lista con los caracteres basta con pasarla directamente al constructor `lista = list(cadena)`.

Por otro lado, el carácter `\` se usa para denotar secuencias de escape (`\n`, `\t`, `\U`, `\s`, etc), necesitas escaparlo si quieres que forme parte de la cadena en sí (`\\`).

Una forma simple y eficiente (solo dos iteraciones sobre la cadena) de hacer lo que quieres es usar `collections.Counter` para contar las apariciones de cada carácter en la cadena, luego basta con iterar sobre la misma y construir una nueva cadena en base a la explicada sustitución:

```
cad = "Camara"

counter= Counter(cad)
new_cad = "".join("/" if counter[char] == 1 else "\\" for char in cad)
```

> ```
> >>> print(new_cad)
> /\/\/\
> ```